# Converting a TensorFlow sess.run to a @tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

How can I edit the `sessions.run` function so that it runs on Tensorflow 2.0?

```
  with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    start = time.time()
    results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0],
                      {input_operation.outputs[0]: t})
```

I read the documentation [over here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) and learned that you have to change a function like this:

```
  normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])
  sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
  result = sess.run(normalized)

  return result
```

to this:

```
def myFunctionToReplaceSessionRun(resized,input_mean,input_std):
    return tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])

normalized = myFunctionToReplaceSessionRun(resized,input_mean,input_std)
```

but I'm unable to figure out how to change the first one.

Here's a bit of context, I was trying out [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016) code lab, and in this found that the `sess.run`, that was giving me trouble.

[This is the command line output when running the `label_images` file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg7mH.png)

[And this is the function that gave errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay1NQ.png)

Answer (score -1):

With TensorFlow 1.x, we used to create `tf.placeholder` tensors by which the data could enter the graph. We used a `feed_dict=` along with the `tf.Session()` object.

In TensorFlow 2.0, we can directly feed the data to the graph as eager execution is enabled by default. With the `@tf.function` annotation, we can include the function directly in our graph. The [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function) say,

> At the centre of this merger is `tf.function`, which allows you to
>   transform a subset of Python syntax into portable, high-performance
>   TensorFlow graphs.

Here's a simple example from the docs,

```
@tf.function
def simple_nn_layer(x, y):
  return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, y))


x = tf.random.uniform((3, 3))
y = tf.random.uniform((3, 3))

simple_nn_layer(x, y)
```

Now, looking into your problem, you can convert your function like,

```
@tf.function
def get_output_operation( input_op ):
    # The function goes here
    # from here return `results`

results = get_output_operation( some_input_op )
```

In simple and less precise words, the placeholder tensors are transformed to function arguments, the `tensor` in `sess.run( tensor )` is returned by the function. All this happens in a `@tf.function` annotated function.